# How to change style "?spinnerstyle" color?

Tags: android, android-styles

How can I change this line with triangle to different color?

[image]

This image shows blue (which is obvious not reachable normally), but default is gray.
And my aim is to turn this gray `underline with triangle` into holo light blue.

My code:

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinnerRadio"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?spinnerStyle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Kanał główny" />
```

I believe there is any xml way to just force color instead recreating wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot just specify the accent color of your controls, you have to provide your own graphic resources, mostly with 9-patches images. Then you have to override the control style to use them

By chance, the wonderful [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com) saves you the chore of doing this yourself!

Comment: yeah, but it gives me gray instead holo light blue

Comment: Because the holo style is gray until activated. Then the accent color is used. If you want an always colored spinner, you should use **Colored Spinner**

Comment: I understand you, but I am using in my code TextView, I just need background to halucinate fake spinner

Comment: You have all the things you need. Just use the Colored Spinner style generated by Android Holo Colors instead of `?spinnerStyle`. Can I ask you why you want to do this? This might not be a very good id from a UX perspective